# obtaining IDSI statistics using ERA5-Land and CHIRPS product, Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

obtaining IDSI statistics using ERA5-Land and CHIRPS product, but it was showing an error: ImageCollection (Error) Parameter 'value' is required.

***https://code.earthengine.google.com/eef6168ecd0097344f4b388d90ca9488***

````
// Define a region of interest for India
var roi = ee.Geometry.Polygon([
  [[68.1, 7.9], [97.4, 7.9], [97.4, 35.5], [68.1, 35.5], [68.1, 7.9]]
]);

// Define the time period for the IDSI calculation
var startDate = '2020-01-01';
var endDate = '2020-12-31';

// Load CHIRPS precipitation data
var chirps = ee.ImageCollection('UCSB-CHG/CHIRPS/PENTAD')
  .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
  .filterBounds(roi)
  .select('precipitation');
print(chirps)
// Load ERA5-Land temperature data
var era5land = ee.ImageCollection('ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/MONTHLY')
  .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
  .filterBounds(roi)
  .select('temperature_2m');
print(era5land)
// Calculate potential evapotranspiration using Thornthwaite method
function calculatePET(image) {
  var tempC = image.select('temperature_2m').subtract(273.15);
  var pet = tempC.multiply(1.8).multiply(0.55).exp()
                  .multiply(12).divide(0.001 * (tempC.multiply(1.8).add(17.8)).pow(2));
  return image.addBands(pet.rename('PET'));
}

var era5landPET = era5land.map(calculatePET);
print(era5landPET)
// Calculate cumulative monthly PET
var monthlyPET = era5landPET.select('PET').sum();

// Load SMAP soil moisture data
var smap = ee.ImageCollection('NASA_USDA/HSL/soil_moisture')
  .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
  .filterBounds(roi)
  .select('Soil moisture profile');
print(smap)
// Calculate average monthly soil moisture
var monthlySoilMoisture = smap.mean();
print(monthlySoilMoisture)
// Calculate IDSI
var idsi = chirps.sum()
  .subtract(monthlyPET)
  .add(monthlySoilMoisture)
  .divide(100); // Scale the IDSI to a more interpretable range

// Display the IDSI on the map
Map.addLayer(idsi, {min: -5, max: 5, palette: ['red', 'yellow', 'green']}, 'IDSI');

// Print IDSI statistics for India
var statistics = idsi.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  geometry: roi,
  scale: 5000,
  maxPixels: 1e9
});

print('Average IDSI for India in 2022:', statistics.get('precipitation'));```
````

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have two issues in your code. At the following function:

```
function calculatePET(image) {
  var tempC = image.select('temperature_2m').subtract(273.15);
  var pet = tempC.multiply(1.8).multiply(0.55).exp()
                  .multiply(12).divide(0.001 * (tempC.multiply(1.8).add(17.8)).pow(2));
  return image.addBands(pet.rename('PET'));
}
```

and at the following Image Collection:

```
var smap = ee.ImageCollection('NASA_USDA/HSL/soil_moisture')
  .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
  .filterBounds(roi)
  .select('Soil moisture profile');
```

I fixed both by using, respectively, an expression and selecting adequate name band (it is 'smp' not 'Soil moisture profile'). For the first one, the error is showing (Parameter 'value' is required) because you are mixing GEE and Java scripts methods for map algebra and this cannot be done. If you have doubts about how to write adequately a formula, you can use an image expression instead; as it can be observed at following lines:

```
function calculatePET(image) {
  var tempC = image.select('temperature_2m').subtract(273.15);
  
  var pet = tempC.expression('exp(tempC*1.8*0.55)*12/(0.001*(tempC*1.8 + 17.8)**2)', 
                             {'tempC': tempC});
  
  //var pet = tempC.multiply(1.8).multiply(0.55).exp()
                  //.multiply(12).divide(0.001 * (tempC.multiply(1.8).add(17.8)).pow(2));

  return pet.addBands(pet.rename('PET'));
  
}
```

Complete code can be obtained from [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/f0168187f6230aad67b8373f1c2ec451). However, I cannot guarantee the validity of results because there are not links to formulas for calculating PET and IDSI values. Running the link code produces the following result:

[image]

Comment: "Thank you for your guidance, clear explanations, and assistance in resolving the issues. Your detailed instructions helped rectify the script errors effectively, and the rewritten code now accurately works for the regions of interest. I truly appreciate your support in improving the script's functionality."